# How to redirect user after form submission

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an app where a user submits a form. As it stands now, I have the form action pointing to a PHP page that processes the data (i.e. sends it to a DB). How can I redirect the user back to the original page after doing this?

Answer (score 1):

use [header().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header("Location: admin/index.php");
```